# Iterate over each row to obtain matches between row values and the rownames of another dataframe df2, then subset df2

Tags: r

For each row of `hallmark.df`, if the `rownames(all.deg)` match any of the values of the given row, retrieve the corresponding rows of `all.deg`.
I also want to keep only the rows of the `hallmark.df` dataframe where there are more than 25 non-NA columns and less than 500 columns

```
subset.df <- by(hallmark.df, seq_len(nrow(hallmark.df)), function(row) 
  ifelse(all.deg[rownames(all.deg) %in% hallmark.df,]))
```

Input:

`all.deg`

```
> dput(all.deg[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(16.0169585624867, 14.3983080662428, 12.7844219145156, 
12.6674945373237, 13.8584047354367, 13.563719599839, 13.6166993468069, 
12.9748157402651, 12.7386065050292, 12.2201616898331, 11.3657998135948, 
11.8253392160132, 12.1132082166185, 11.5123143882139, 10.2967924742924, 
13.7513874043739, 13.2403954818698, 12.4196432226432, 12.4676109090624, 
12.1390647972695, 12.3013113392588, 12.4867673484914, 11.3693921877853, 
10.6359730348998, 10.0122721528039), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("JUNB", "ALDOA", "HLA.A", "THBD", "CD74"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", 
    "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01")))

> dput(hallmark.df[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(V3 = c("JUNB", "PGK1", "FDPS", "ARHGEF2", "CD74"
), V4 = c("CXCL2", "PDK1", "CYP51A1", "CLASP1", "CTNNB1"), V5 = c("ATF3", 
"GBE1", "IDI1", "KIF11", "JAG2"), V6 = c("NFKBIA", "PFKL", "FDFT1", 
"KIF23", "NOTCH1"), V7 = c("ALDOA", "JUNB", "DHCR7", "ALS2", 
"DLL1")), row.names = c("HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB", "HALLMARK_HYPOXIA", 
"HALLMARK_CHOLESTEROL_HOMEOSTASIS", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE", 
"HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING"), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

`HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB`

|  | TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JUNB | 16.0169585624867 | 13.563719599839 | 11.3657998135948 | 13.7513874043739 | 12.3013113392588 |
| CD74 | 13.8584047354367 | 12.2201616898331 | 10.2967924742924 | 12.1390647972695 | 10.0122721528039 |

`HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING`

|  | TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 | TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALDOA | 14.3983080662428 | 13.6166993468069 | 11.8253392160132 | 13.2403954818698 | 12.4867673484914 |
| JUNB | 16.0169585624867 | 13.563719599839 | 11.3657998135948 | 13.7513874043739 | 12.3013113392588 |

```
df.list <- list(HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB, HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING)
```

Related question: [How to subset a dataframe based on matches to another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76707644/how-to-subset-a-dataframe-based-on-matches-to-another-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the 'best' way to solve your problem, but here is one potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
all.deg <- structure(c(16.0169585624867, 14.3983080662428, 12.7844219145156, 
                       12.6674945373237, 13.8584047354367, 13.563719599839, 13.6166993468069, 
                       12.9748157402651, 12.7386065050292, 12.2201616898331, 11.3657998135948, 
                       11.8253392160132, 12.1132082166185, 11.5123143882139, 10.2967924742924, 
                       13.7513874043739, 13.2403954818698, 12.4196432226432, 12.4676109090624, 
                       12.1390647972695, 12.3013113392588, 12.4867673484914, 11.3693921877853, 
                       10.6359730348998, 10.0122721528039), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
                         c("JUNB", "ALDOA", "HLA.A", "THBD", "CD74"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", 
                                                                        "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", 
                                                                        "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01")))

hallmark.df <- structure(list(V3 = c("JUNB", "PGK1", "FDPS", "ARHGEF2", "CD74"
), V4 = c("CXCL2", "PDK1", "CYP51A1", "CLASP1", "CTNNB1"), V5 = c("ATF3", 
                                                                  "GBE1", "IDI1", "KIF11", "JAG2"), V6 = c("NFKBIA", "PFKL", "FDFT1", 
                                                                                                           "KIF23", "NOTCH1"), V7 = c("ALDOA", "JUNB", "DHCR7", "ALS2", 
                                                                                                                                      "DLL1")), row.names = c("HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB", "HALLMARK_HYPOXIA", 
                                                                                                                                                              "HALLMARK_CHOLESTEROL_HOMEOSTASIS", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE", 
                                                                                                                                                              "HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING"), class = "data.frame")

output <- list()
for (i in seq_along(hallmark.df)) {
  output[[rownames(hallmark.df)[i]]] <- all.deg[rownames(all.deg) %in% hallmark.df[,i],]
}

# Remove empty dataframes from the list
clean_list <- output[which(lapply(output, nrow) != 0)]

# export the dataframes to the global env
list2env(clean_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

ls(pattern = "HALLMARK*")
#> [1] "HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB"    "HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING"

HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB
#>      TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
#> JUNB        16.01696        13.56372        11.36580        13.75139
#> CD74        13.85840        12.22016        10.29679        12.13906
#>      TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01
#> JUNB        12.30131
#> CD74        10.01227
HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING
#>       TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
#> JUNB         16.01696        13.56372        11.36580        13.75139
#> ALDOA        14.39831        13.61670        11.82534        13.24040
#>       TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01
#> JUNB         12.30131
#> ALDOA        12.48677
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Edit 1

To keep rows of the hallmark.df dataframe where there are more than 25 non-NA columns and less than 500 non-NA columns you can use:

```r
hallmark %>%
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) >= 25 | rowSums(!is.na(.)) <= 500)
```

Comment: Ahh thanks! I will try it. Furthermore, how do I keep only the rows of the `hallmark.df` dataframe where there are more than 25 non-NA columns and less than than 500 columns?

Comment: Thanks again for responding to both questions. Unfortunately, the dataframe formats for both questions are different so I'm still unsure how to keep only the rows of the `hallmark.df` dataframe where there are more than 25 non-NA columns and less than than 500 columns

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem. Unfortunately, I have another follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709524/failed-to-coerce-non-range-columns-to-numeric

Comment: I've added a reference at the bottom of my 2nd question

Comment: did you manage to look at the other question? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into it now - the problem seems to be with the [createMAE](https://rdrr.io/bioc/ELMER/man/createMAE.html) function call, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I'll post an answer if/when I figure it out

Comment: Essentially, the desired output is similar to this question but with a different dataset (methylation data)

Answer (score 1):

We can transform row names as a column, then it is easily done by {tidyverse}:

```r
all.deg <- structure(c(16.0169585624867, 14.3983080662428, 12.7844219145156, 
                       12.6674945373237, 13.8584047354367, 13.563719599839, 13.6166993468069, 
                       12.9748157402651, 12.7386065050292, 12.2201616898331, 11.3657998135948, 
                       11.8253392160132, 12.1132082166185, 11.5123143882139, 10.2967924742924, 
                       13.7513874043739, 13.2403954818698, 12.4196432226432, 12.4676109090624, 
                       12.1390647972695, 12.3013113392588, 12.4867673484914, 11.3693921877853, 
                       10.6359730348998, 10.0122721528039), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
                         c("JUNB", "ALDOA", "HLA.A", "THBD", "CD74"), c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01", 
                                                                        "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01", 
                                                                        "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01")))
hallmark.df <- structure(list(V3 = c("JUNB", "PGK1", "FDPS", "ARHGEF2", "CD74"), 
                              V4 = c("CXCL2", "PDK1", "CYP51A1", "CLASP1", "CTNNB1"), 
                              V5 = c("ATF3", "GBE1", "IDI1", "KIF11", "JAG2"),
                              V6 = c("NFKBIA", "PFKL", "FDFT1", "KIF23", "NOTCH1"),
                              V7 = c("ALDOA", "JUNB", "DHCR7", "ALS2", "DLL1")), 
                         row.names = c("HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB", "HALLMARK_HYPOXIA", 
                                       "HALLMARK_CHOLESTEROL_HOMEOSTASIS", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE", 
                                       "HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING"), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)
hallmark.df |> 
  as_tibble(rownames = "row") |> 
  pivot_longer(-row) |> 
  inner_join(
    all.deg |> 
      as_tibble(rownames = "value"),
    by = "value"
  ) |> 
  split(~row) |> 
  map(
    ~ . |> 
      select(-row, -name) |> 
      column_to_rownames("value")
  )
#> $HALLMARK_HYPOXIA
#>      TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
#> JUNB        16.01696        13.56372         11.3658        13.75139
#>      TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01
#> JUNB        12.30131
#> 
#> $HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB
#>       TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
#> JUNB         16.01696        13.56372        11.36580        13.75139
#> ALDOA        14.39831        13.61670        11.82534        13.24040
#>       TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01
#> JUNB         12.30131
#> ALDOA        12.48677
#> 
#> $HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING
#>      TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01
#> CD74         13.8584        12.22016        10.29679        12.13906
#>      TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01
#> CD74        10.01227
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Would you mind to check the following, which I added minutes ago: I also want to keep only the rows of the hallmark.df dataframe where there are more than 25 non-NA columns and less than 500 columns