# failed to coerce non-range columns to 'numeric'

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I would like to iterate the following code for a list of data frames `mrna.pathways`.

For a single dataframe (e.g., ADIPOGENESIS):

```
library(biomaRt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ELMER)

exp <- mrna.pathways$ADIPOGENESIS
genes <- rownames(exp)
ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "genes", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", GRCh = 37, verbose = T)
ensembl <- useDataset(dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", mart = ensembl)
g_list <- getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id','hgnc_symbol'), 
                filters='hgnc_symbol',values=genes,
                mart=ensembl, useCache = FALSE)
g_list <- g_list[!duplicated(g_list$ensembl_gene_id) | duplicated(g_list$ensembl_gene_id, fromLast = TRUE), ]

idx <- exp %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'symbol') %>%
  pull(symbol) %>%
  match(table = g_list$hgnc_symbol)
exp <- exp %>%
  mutate(row_name = g_list$ensembl_gene_id[idx]) %>%
  group_by(row_name) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  column_to_rownames('row_name')

exp$rowname <- NULL
exp <- exp[, colnames(exp) %in% colnames(meth)]

exp <- na.omit(exp)
meth <- na.omit(meth)

sample.info <- S4Vectors::DataFrame(primary=colnames(meth))
TSS <- getTSS(genome="hg38", TSS=list(upstream=2000, downstream=2000))

promoter.features <- get.feature.probe(feature = NULL,TSS,genome = "hg38",met.platform = "450K",TSS.range = list(upstream = 2000, downstream = 2000),promoter = T,rm.chr = NULL)

mae <- createMAE(exp = exp, met = meth, met.platform ="450K",colData = sample.info,filter.probes = promoter.features,genome = "hg38") 

meth.adipogenesis <- meth[rownames(meth) %in% mae@ExperimentList@listData$`DNA methylation`@rowRanges@ranges@NAMES,]
meth.adipogenesis <- meth.adipogenesis[ , order(names(meth.adipogenesis))]
```

My attempt:

```
ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart = "genes", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", GRCh = 37, verbose = T)
ensembl <- useDataset(dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", mart = ensembl)
g_list <- getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id','hgnc_symbol'), 
                filters='hgnc_symbol',values=genes,
                mart=ensembl, useCache = FALSE)
g_list <- g_list[!duplicated(g_list$ensembl_gene_id) | duplicated(g_list$ensembl_gene_id, fromLast = TRUE), ]

lapply(mrna.pathways, function(x) {
  genes <- rownames(x)
  idx <- x %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = 'symbol') %>%
    pull(symbol) %>%
    match(table = g_list$hgnc_symbol)
  x <- x %>%
    mutate(row_name = g_list$ensembl_gene_id[idx]) %>%
    group_by(row_name) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    column_to_rownames('row_name')
  
  x$rowname <- NULL
  x <- x[, colnames(x) %in% colnames(meth)]
  
  x <- na.omit(x)
  meth <- na.omit(meth)
  
  sample.info <- S4Vectors::DataFrame(primary=colnames(meth))
  TSS <- getTSS(genome="hg38", TSS=list(upstream=2000, downstream=2000))
  
  promoter.features <- get.feature.probe(feature = NULL,TSS,genome = "hg38",met.platform = "450K",TSS.range = list(upstream = 2000, downstream = 2000),promoter = T,rm.chr = NULL)
  
  mae <- createMAE(exp = x, met = meth, met.platform ="450K",colData = sample.info,filter.probes = promoter.features,genome = "hg38") 
  
  # methylation.pathways <- meth[rownames(meth) %in% mae@ExperimentList@listData$`DNA methylation`@rowRanges@ranges@NAMES,]
  # methylation.pathways <- methylation.pathways[ , order(names(methylation.pathways))]
  x} )
```

Traceback:

```
Error in makeSummarizedExperimentFromDataFrame(aux[, !grepl("external_gene_name|ensembl_gene_id|entrezgene",  : 
  failed to coerce non-range columns to 'numeric'
In addition: Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :

# List of dataframes
methylation.pathways <- list(HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB, HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING)
```

Input:

```
> dput(meth[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01 = c(2.18703449627152, 2.19469161550175, 
-4.08698324454124, -4.1561371941108, -3.45287644116425), TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 = c(2.32778952882647, 
2.34278400744779, -3.75343850250278, -4.30774465586903, -4.32830755550417
), TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 = c(2.52979099210225, 3.14802506855705, -2.14602292062711, 
-4.36197762548339, -4.40610672766836), TCGA.Y8.A897.01 = c(2.14168822194255, 
1.80634363823259, -3.47041057815363, -4.29818228422328, -4.41784030526389
), TCGA.Y8.A896.01 = c(2.65073982842331, 2.61095380298199, -1.89501392291243, 
-4.14543318132608, -4.11547721741994)), row.names = c("cg00000957", 
"cg00001349", "cg00001583", "cg00002028", "cg00002719"), class = "data.frame")

> hallmark
structure(list(V3 = c("JUNB", "PGK1", "FDPS", "ARHGEF2", "CD74"
), V4 = c("CXCL2", "PDK1", "CYP51A1", "CLASP1", "CTNNB1"), V5 = c("ATF3", 
"GBE1", "IDI1", "KIF11", "JAG2"), V6 = c("NFKBIA", "PFKL", "FDFT1", 
"KIF23", "NOTCH1"), V7 = c("ALDOA", "JUNB", "DHCR7", "ALS2", 
"DLL1")), row.names = c("HALLMARK_TNFA_SIGNALING_VIA_NFKB", "HALLMARK_HYPOXIA", 
"HALLMARK_CHOLESTEROL_HOMEOSTASIS", "HALLMARK_MITOTIC_SPINDLE", 
"HALLMARK_WNT_BETA_CATENIN_SIGNALING"), class = "data.frame")
```

Reference:

https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/37/Supplement_1/i443/6319702#409222216

"That is, the matrix B consists of samples in rows and genes for a given pathway in columns. Using principal component analysis (PCA), the matrix B was decomposed into uncorrelated components, yielding Gpi∈Rn×q
⁠, where q is the number of principal components (PCs). This task for the pathway pi was also carried out on the CNV matrix (C) and DNA methylation matrix (M), yielding Cpi, Mpi∈Rn×q
⁠, respectively. The process was repeated for all 146 pathways, resulting in the merged matrices Gp, Cp and Mp∈Rn×146q
for the 146 pathways."

Comment: hi! have you tried debugging the code? Which line does it break on?

Comment: would be great to have a minimal reproducible example (emphasis on minimal)

Comment: The code break on `mae <- createMAE(exp = x, met = meth, met.platform ="450K",colData = sample.info,filter.probes = promoter.features,genome = "hg38") `. It worked in the single dataframe example but not in the `lapply` code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of `mrna.pathways`? Is it a list of dataframes? If so, that might one of your problems: iterating through the list with lapply might be giving you an 'unexpected' output, e.g.

```r
d1 <- data.frame("test1" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 "test2" = c(2,3,4,5,6))

d2 <- data.frame("test3" = c("a","b","c"),
                 "test4" = c("d", "e", "f"))

df <- list("df1" = d1, "df2" = d2)

df
#> $df1
#>   test1 test2
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     3
#> 3     3     4
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     6
#> 
#> $df2
#>   test3 test4
#> 1     a     d
#> 2     b     e
#> 3     c     f

lapply(df, function(x) {
  a <- x
  print(a)
})
#>   test1 test2
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     3
#> 3     3     4
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     6
#>   test3 test4
#> 1     a     d
#> 2     b     e
#> 3     c     f
#> $df1
#>   test1 test2
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     3
#> 3     3     4
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     6
#> 
#> $df2
#>   test3 test4
#> 1     a     d
#> 2     b     e
#> 3     c     f

# with a for loop
for (x in df) {
  a <- x
  print(a)
}
#>   test1 test2
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     3
#> 3     3     4
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     6
#>   test3 test4
#> 1     a     d
#> 2     b     e
#> 3     c     f

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  a <- df[i]
  print(a)
  list2env(a, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
#> $df1
#>   test1 test2
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     3
#> 3     3     4
#> 4     4     5
#> 5     5     6
#> 
#> $df2
#>   test3 test4
#> 1     a     d
#> 2     b     e
#> 3     c     f
ls(pattern = "df.")
#> [1] "df1" "df2"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `mrna.pathways` is the output from the previous question. So yes, it's a list of dataframes.